# xcode5 for iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I have requirement for do app with iOS7. Now i'm uisng xcode4.3 It supports deployment 4.3 to 6.1. If i install xcode5 which one the minimum deployment target. I read doc, they mentioned "64-bit compatible applications are only supported with a minimum deployment target of iOS 6 or later" I didn't get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

64 bit apps are only applicable to the A7 chip (which is 64 bit native) in the iPhone 5s.

I think Apple are thinking of doing fat binaries down the road, but for now, you can build 32 and 64 bit in Xcode 5, depending on your target platform.

To answer your question yes you can support as early a version of iOS as you wish on Xcode5

Comment: If i develop an app with xcode4.3, minimum deployment target is 4.3. Now my app is support for ios5,6. Is it support for ios7?

Comment: Yes it will work on iOS 7 with a deployment target of iOS 5. Once you don't use any deprecated methods/APIs.

Comment: If use deprecated method what will happen?

Comment: You will get a warning from the compiler, and sometimes, will cause your app to be rejected, but you will know when you compile in Xcode 5 if there is any issue :)